# Angular 4: How to get and display the multiple data using angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a problem to get the data in angular.

HTML:

```html
<div class='col-md-6'>
  <div class='side-panel' style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class='headTxt'>
      <h5 *ngFor="let items of menuList">{{items.txt}}</h5>
      <div *ngFor="let items of menuList">{{items.item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```js
export class FoodItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  menuList;
  constructor() {
    this.menuList = [
      {txt:'Briyani',item:"chicken briyani"},
      {txt:'Indian veg rice'},
      {txt:'Rice & noodles'}, 
      {txt:'grill & shawarma'}, 
      {txt:'tandoori'}, 
      {txt:'chicken starter'}, 
      {txt:'egg dishes'},
      {txt:'Briyani'}, 
      {txt:'Briyani'},
    ];
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am trying to get this type of output:

[image: 1]

But, am getting like this. Please, help.

[image: 2]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by following below codes.

First of all create a custom pipe as shown below

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<any>, field: string): Array<any> {
    const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur)=> {
      if(!prev[cur[field]]) {
        prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
      } else {
        prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
      }
      return prev;
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => return { key, value: groupedObj[key] });
  }
}
```

Then add the following in your component where you have to inject the custom pipe previously created.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      <div *ngFor="let menu of menuList | groupBy:'txt' ">
       <span style="font-weight: bold;">{{ menu.key }} </span> 
       <div *ngFor="let val of menu.value">{{ val }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  pipes: [GroupByPipe],
  directives: []
})
```

I have slightly modified the JSON array to support the format you mentioned in the question

```
this.menuList=[ {txt:'Briyani',item:"chicken briyani"},
      {txt:'Indian rice',item:"veg"},
      {txt:'Rice & noodles',item:"veg"}, 
      {txt:'grill & shawarma',item:"fish"}, 
      {txt:'tandoori',item:"chicken"}, 
      {txt:'starter',item:"chicken"}, 
      {txt:'dishes',item:"egg"},
      {txt:'Briyani',item:"mutton briyani"}, 
      {txt:'Briyani',item:"fish briyani"}];
```

if you have JSON like this

```
    this.menuList=[{
    "txt": "Briyani",
    "item": [{
        "type": "Chicken Briyani",
        "price": "180",
        "img": "assets/images/3.JPG"
    }, {
        "type": "Mutton Briyani",
        "price": "180",
        "img": "assets/images/3.JPG"
    }, {
        "type": "Prawn Briyani",
        "price": "180",
        "img": "assets/images/3.JPG"
    }]
}, {
    "txt": "Indian Rice",
    "item": [{
        "type": "Chicken Rice",
        "price": "180",
        "img": "assets/images/3.JPG"
    }, {
        "type": "Fish Rice",
        "price": "180",
        "img": "assets/images/3.JPG"
    }]
}];
```

then you can follow the code below to achieve your task.

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menuList">
  <h5>{{menu.txt}}</h5>
  <div *ngFor="let it of menu.item">
    <span>{{it.type}}</span>
    <span>{{it.price}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/CtyhYv?p=preview)

I hope this will fix your problem. If any suggestions or doubts let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Atchaya what was your doubt?

Comment: May i use like this:this.menuList = [
      {
        txt:'Briyani',
        item:[
          {type:"Chicken Briyani",price:'180',img:'assets/images/3.JPG'},
          {type:"Mutton Briyani",price:'180',img:'assets/images/3.JPG'},
          {type:"Prawn Briyani",price:'180',img:'assets/images/3.JPG'},
        ]
        
    },

Comment: Yes you can. In that case you don't need to create custom pipe, but you have to loop two times to list the items which will affect performance of the application. If your application is not a performance specific one then you can follow the second option. check the answer I have edited my answer

Comment: @Atchaya then please kindly make the answer as correct :)

Comment: @Atchaya if you don't mind can you make it as correct answer since it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have two *ngFor after each other, instead of embeding the second one in the first. Also, your second ngFor is wrong, if you want to iterate trough the items of a menulist element. Try this (I changed the names for better readability):

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
  <div class='side-panel' style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div *ngFor="let entries of menuList" class='headTxt'>
      <h5>{{entries.txt}}</h5>
      <div *ngFor="let items of entries">{{items}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```